# Xml Functions in iphone

Tags: iphone

With Out using xml Functions:

didStartElement

foundCharacters

didEndElement

how to get Xml datas

Comment: Did you mean without using NSXMLParser delegate methods you want to parse XML ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an NSMutableString for example, and each time foundCharacters method is called, you append the new characters to the string, once the didEndElement gets called, you know your mutable string is complete for the previous element

Answer (score 0):

Look at TBXML http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html